# Flutter: how to build the logic of moving blocks when changing the orientation of a mobile device?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Using flutter, i need to place in the mobile device two blocks  so that:

- in **vertical** position `block_A` was on **top**, and `block_B` was on the **bottom**
- in **horizontal** position `block_A` is on the **left** and `block_B` is on the **right**

[image of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYkSA.jpg)

---

I implemented this through Wrap, setting the width of the block based on the width of the current screen, and Wrap put down the block automatically. But I'm not sure if this is the right decision.

```
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    double mainBoxWidth = screenSize.width / 100 * (screenSize.width > screenSize.height ? 50 : 100) ;
    double mainBoxHeight = screenSize.height / 100 * (screenSize.width > screenSize.height ? 100 : 50) ;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Wrap(
          children: [

            Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text("block_A"),
                ),
              width: mainBoxWidth,
              height: mainBoxHeight,
              ),


            Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text("block_B"),
                ),
              width: mainBoxWidth, 
              height: mainBoxHeight,           
              ),

          ],
        ),
      ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.green
    );
  }
}
```

Please tell me how to correctly implement this task. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As with most things in Flutter, there are a few ways this could be done. Here's one way:

```
class MainPage extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    final isLandscape = screenSize.width > screenSize.height;
    return Scaffold(
      body: isLandscape
          ? Row(
              children: _buildChildren(),
            )
          : Column(
              children: _buildChildren(),
            ),
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _buildChildren() {
    return [
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.yellow,
          child: Center(
            child: Text("block_A"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          child: Center(
            child: Text("block_B"),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ];
  }
}
```